# How do I get more ammo?

Tags: let-it-die

Further up in the Tower of Barbs, enemies start using firearms like assault rifles, sniper rifles, and handguns. I noticed that even when they run out of ammo, they don't break like the Irons do, which leads me to believe there's a reason they stay in my inventory.

Is there a way to get more ammo for guns? Or should I just toss them as soon as they run out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no means in which to refill ammo for firearms, once you run out you are usually good to just drop it and move on.  The only thing that extra durability is good for is secondary moves that some of them have, which usually involve a melee bash that consumes durability quite rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

The supers and R1/L1 secondary attacks use lots of durability, even if the gun runs out of ammo, you can still use its Super. Usually I use the super after I run out of ammo, as it usually breaks right after. I noticed un-upgraded assault rifles tend to run out of durability before they expend all the ammo.

While there is no way to get more ammo, you can use dragonshrooms to give yourself 10/20 seconds of infinite ammo, and there are fun shrooms later on that restores durability on a weapon. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is borderline a comment on the previous answer.  It doesn't add much besides being able to still use the supers - which is more like a comment.